# Changes made in .aspx not being reflected when i debug / rebuild in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, visual-studio, git

I've been working on a site and when i do changes to my .aspx file and debug or rebuild it, the changes are not shown. I need to have to close my visual studio program and open the solution, debug it again before i can see the changes.

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: have you tried performing a forced refresh in your browser (ctrl-F5/ctrl-shift-r)? This will force the browser to get it from the server again, rather than use any possible cached copy.

Comment: Are you talking at runtime when you run the application, or you don't see the change in the Visual Studio designer?  I couldn't quite tell from the wording...

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down the Development Server (the little yellow icon in the notification area) before you rerun the program.  Things might be getting cached.